# Site 9 DXA Example site publishing issue

Tags: dxa, topology-manager, sites-9, dxa-2.1

[image]

I’m learning and trying to setup DXA 2.1 example site on Site 9 environment.

I tried to follow the steps mentioned in the document (we have publishing working for other publications already) When I try to publish any page of example DXA site, nothing happens. Attached screens

Please help with setting up topology mgr.

[image]

Comment: For me seems like Mapping from Web application to Publication may be missing, Can you run this "Get-TtmMapping" PowerShell cmd on the CM server and update the question.

Comment: @Velmurugan Updated question with image

Comment: Can you double-check that example publication Id has a mapping?

Comment: @Velmurugan No, I dont see the example publication mapping.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, The mapping is missing.

**Create the Mappings and then publish and test, it should work:**

```
Add-TtmMapping -ID Mapping1 -CmEnvironmentId Tridioncm_localhost -PublicationID tcm:0-5-1 -WebApplicationId Website1_RootWebApp -RelativeUrl /
```

**Note:**
CmEnvironmentId, PublicationId, and WebApplicationId should be your environment-specific values

For **PublicationId** - Note down your example website publication Id.

For **CmEnvironmentId** - run this Powershell cmd **Get-TtmCmEnvironment** and note down the Id.

For **WebApplicationId** - first, run this Powershell cmd **Get-TtmWebsite** identify the base URL and cd environment and note down the Id, and then run the **Get-TtmWebApplication -WebsiteId Website1**, note down the Id, once you know all the parameters values of the Add-TtmMapping then proceed to create the mapping and publish and test.

The example website configuration should look like this for your reference, but the values and Ids are differs based on customer-specific values.

```
PS C:\Users\vagrant> Get-TtmCmEnvironment

CoreServiceRootUrl     : net.tcp://localhost:2660
WebsiteRootUrl         : http://localhost:80
CoreServiceCredentials : "AuthenticationType":"Windows", "UserName":"VAGRANT-2016\MTSUser", "Password":"********"
Id                     : Tridioncm_localhost
ExtensionProperties    : {}


PS C:\Users\vagrant> Get-TtmWebsite

BaseUrls             : {http://localhost:8852}
CdEnvironmentId      : CdEnvironment1
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        : 
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite}
Id                   : Website1
ExtensionProperties  : {}

PS C:\Users\vagrant> Get-TtmWebApplication

ContextUrl           : /
WebsiteId            : Website1
EnvironmentPurpose   : Staging
CdEnvironment        : 
ScopedRepositoryKeys : {DxaSiteType, DxaExampleSite}
Id                   : Website1_RootWebApp
ExtensionProperties  : {}

PS C:\Users\vagrant> Get-TtmMapping

CmEnvironmentId     : Tridioncm_localhost
PublicationId       : tcm:0-5-1
EnvironmentPurpose  : Staging
WebApplicationId    : Website1_RootWebApp
RelativeUrl         : /
PrimaryMappedUrl    : http://localhost:8852/
IsOffline           : False
CdEnvironment       : 
Id                  : Mapping1
ExtensionProperties : {}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: thanks a lot. This resolved the issue.

Comment: I am able to publish the pages in tridion. Now as per the documentation, I ran below command, and after that tried to run the application. But getting error that "No matching Localization found for URL 'http://localhost:8888/'". In this application I dont see configuration files where we need to define the publication Id and all.  Examaple .web-install.ps1 -distDestination "C:\inetpub\wwwroot\DXA_Staging" 
-webName "DXA Staging" -sitePort 8888 -discoveryServiceUrl http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc

Comment: Please let me know

Comment: I'm getting this error, please help.     ERROR - Sdl.Web.Delivery.Service.InvalidServiceEndpoint: Unable to retrieve context engine service uri from discovery service. No ContextServiceCapability found!

Comment: Good to know you resolved the issue, please accept the answer and raise a separate question for other issues